# Apt upgrade is not working "manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

0

when I run the `sudo apt upgrade get` this error.
**E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.**

when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command system freeze at Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogdand ssh connection breaks after sometime.

> root@beautiful-haslett:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
> Setting up apparmor (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2) ... Reloading AppArmor profiles

> Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the command is suggests you fix the issue with?  ps: providing your release is almost always beneficial... your paste appears to fit *jammy* (22.04) but it's better if we're not guessing! as release details are helpful in picking problems (eg. if my *jammy* detail was incorrect that's key detail!)

Comment: yes I run the command the system get freeze please check the attached image in above message.